# Twice differentiable function in a point implies differentiability in a neighborhood of the point

Tags: derivatives, frechet-derivative

I want to prove the following result that I found in the literature:

> Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces and $U$ an open set of X. If $f:U\rightarrow Y$ is a twice differentiable function in $a\in U$, then there exists $r>0$ such that $f$ is differentiable in $x$, for all $x\in B(a,r)$, where $B(a,r)$ is the open ball with center $a$ and radius $r$.

My attempt:

We want to show that $\exists r>0$ such that $\forall x\in B(a,r)$ and $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that if $\|h\|<\delta$, then $\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h\|<\varepsilon\|h\|$.

Since $f$ is twice differentiable in $a$, then $f$ is differentiable in $a$, $f$ is continuous in $a$ and $Df$ is continuous in $a$. Let $\varepsilon>0$.

$\textbf{(1)}$ $f$ differentiable in $a\iff(\exists\eta>0$ such that if $\|h\|<\eta\implies\|f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h\|<\varepsilon\|h\|$)

$\textbf{(2)}$ $f$ continuous in $a\iff(\exists\delta_1>0$ such that if $\|x-a\|<\delta_1\implies\|f(x)-f(a)\|<\varepsilon)$

$\textbf{(3)}$ $Df$ continuous in $a\iff(\exists\delta_2>0$ such that if $\|x-a\|<\delta_2\implies\|Df(x)-Df(a)\|<\varepsilon)$.

Taking $R=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, $\delta=\min\{\frac{R}{2},\eta\}$ and $x\in B(a,\frac{R}{2})$, we have that

$\textbf{(**)}\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h\|\leq\|f(x+h)-f(a+h)\|+\|f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h\|+\|f(a)-f(x)\|+\|Df(a)h-Df(x)h\|$

By $\textbf{(2)}$, we have that $\|f(x+h)-f(a+h)\|\leq\|f(x+h)-f(a)\|+\|f(a)-f(a+h)\|<2\varepsilon$ since $\|x+h-a\|<\delta_1$ and $\|a+h-a\|<\delta_1$; and also, $\|f(a)-f(x)\|<\varepsilon$ since $\|x-a\|<\delta_1$.

By $\textbf{(1)}$, we have that $\|f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h\|<\varepsilon\|h\|$ since $\|h\|<\delta<\eta$.

By $\textbf{(3)}$, we have that $\|Df(a)h-Df(x)h\|\leq\|Df(a)-Df(x)\|\|h\|<\varepsilon\|h\|$ since $\|x-a\|<\frac{R}{2}<\delta_2$.

Finally, from the above lines and $\textbf{(**)}$, we can conclude that

$\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h\|<3\varepsilon+2\varepsilon\|h\|$.

Here is my question: as you can see, the first addend ($3\varepsilon$) does not depend on $\|h\|$, so I cannot conclude that $\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h\|<\varepsilon\|h\|$ as it is required, and I think it is not possible to choose $\varepsilon$ as $\varepsilon\|h\|$ in order to get the desired result.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You say Df is continuous at a (continuous in operator norm), which wouldn't make sense unless Df exists in a neighborhoood of a.

Comment: In that sense I must understand that f is differentiable in a neighborhood of the point a because as Df is continuous in a then Df must exist in a neighborhood of a. Am I right? And if this is the right answer, is there some way to prove the assertion by using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ process as I have tried? Or is it completely unnecessary?

Comment: Right, if you want to prove it from scratch you probably don't want to use that Df is continuous, since this is essentially assuming what you're trying to prove.  I would start with this: If $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$ then by definition there is a neighborhood of $a$ where (definition of twice differentiable).

Comment: You are right! To prove from scratch is enough to use the existence of a neighborhood of $a$ given by the definition of twice differentiable function in $a$ and we have that $Df$ must exist in the neighborhood given above, and hence f is differentiable in a neighborhood of $a$. Am I right?

Comment: You want to prove Df exists in the neighborhood using the epsilon-delta stuff (by proving the definition you have in the body of your question).

Comment: The problem that I have to prove by epsilon-delta stuff is that in certain part of the prove I must use the continuity of  f because as I have in my previous proof I add some terms in order to use the definition of diferentiability and continuous of f. In that way, at the end of the prove I can't attain all the terms depending on the norm of the increment h, because the continuity of f doesn't give that term. In that sense I return to my original question...

Comment: For example, if you see my work and you don't consider the consequence #3 (continuity of Df in a), how can you continue? You suggest the introduction of twice diferentiability, but if a use it, I must introduce in some estimate the second derivative.. So in order to do that I must add and substract some terms and consequently and must use the continuity of f, and the problem persist... How can I fix this problem?